# Android RecyclerView Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

There are lots of same question on this problem and in solution they said update gradle version but I'm using latest version then also I'm facing this issue
kindly help me with this.

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "bd8994644a28e456358162533e01319cc08f4ef8"
>   Fix plugin version and sync project
> Open File

[image]

Comment: you should not be mixing different versions of the support library items, they all should be the same version and dont use `+` in the versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my **Android support library**, **Local Maven repository for support Libraries** and **Tools**
and added this in build.gradle and it worked.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi change to and test :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this versions

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```